# Ajax Tooltip using Mootools not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, mootools-events

I would like to create a Mootools ajax tooltip with following script

```
new MooTooltips({
                        extra:{  
                            0: {
                                'id':this.id,
                                'ajax':'http://www.fesn.cz/communities/tip.php',
                                'ajax_message': 'Loading... please wait.',
                                'position':1,
                                'sticky':false
                            }
                        },
                        ToolTipClass:'ToolTips',    // tooltip display class
                        toolTipPosition:-1, // -1 top; 1: bottom - set this as a default position value if none is set on the element
                        sticky:false,        // remove tooltip if closed
                        fromTop: 0,        // distance from mouse or object
                        fromLeft: -55,    // distance from left
                        duration: 300,        // fade effect transition duration
                        fadeDistance: 20    // the distance the tooltip starts the morph
                    });

    }
```

Script demo is here,

http://jsfiddle.net/kyathi/mHEjV/.

Idea behind is while mouseenter every tippable class will show an ajax tooltip. But script fails to call ajax script at first time when hover the div and it will involk thereafter.

Any idea to fix the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I commet out the `toolTipPosition:-1` And not its displaying the tooltip. But the alignment is out.

http://jsfiddle.net/mHEjV/1/

Answer (score 0):

the `$$` function return always an array.. you are adding the events on an array and not on the elements of the array. You need to do a loop or use the `each()` method:

```
$$('div.tippable').each(function(div){
    div.addEvents({
    mouseenter:function(){
    ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mHEjV/2/

And it wont work in jsfiddle since the ajax call uses a different domain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests

Good Luck